# How to change Response Header Content-Type from txt/html, Ubuntu, tomcat8

Tags: javascript, spring, ubuntu, tomcat, server

I am calling API to return a `JSON` with all needed objects (notes):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      var response = xhr.responseText;
               //do stuff with response        
    }
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://mydomain:8080/notes/all', true);
    xhr.send(null);
  });
```

HTTP request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/all"}, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public  @ResponseBody List<Note> getAllNotes() {
    return noteService.getAllNotes();
}
```

When I run locally on Mac, everything works. My Response header has Content-Type: application/java, and Request accepts it.

However, when I upload my .war to `Ubuntu 16.04` server, Request header's Content-Type changes to `txt/html`, and I get

> 404 Page Not Found

. 
I am using `tomcat8.5.5` on both machines.

How do I specify/change the Request Header Content-Type?

Images of headers:
running on remote [image: Ubuntu]
and local [image: Mac]

Comment: Content Type is text/html because Error page 404 is returned which is a html page and is valid content type. What you need to solve is why 404 is returned on Ubuntu. Referring to your Javascript code, is that code is served from same application?.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that I had `<script src="noteAPI.js"></script>` declaration in BOTH index.html and notes.html. I have removed this declaration from index.html and it worked!